# marker-end didn't work with firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js

i had an issue about the marker-end using d3, i used it in a gwt project,i created a file .js in which i put all my svg elements including this marker-end, and the problem is when i run the project in local-host with Firefox, the marker-end is displayed correctly, but when i deploy my project in the web server, then here comes the problem, the marker-end dispears!!

this is how i use the marker-end,no surprise here

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)``
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)")
  .attr("d", diagonal);
```

does someone know why ? thanks !!

Comment: Are you using an image as marker-end that you forgot to copy to the webserver?